# Getting full JFileChooser input and preventing other actions from being taken

Tags: java, swing, filesystems, filenames, jfilechooser

I have a `FileSaver` class that extends the JFileChooser class so that I can control file filters and validate input. Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

private class FileSaver extends JFileChooser {

    private String pngDescription = "*.png";
    private String jpgDescription = "*.png";

    public FileSaver() {
        super();
        FileNameExtensionFilter jpgFilter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(jpgDescription, "jpg");
        addChoosableFileFilter(jpgFilter);
        addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter(pngDescription, "png"));
        setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        setFileFilter(jpgFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void approveSelection() {
        boolean approveFileName = false;
        File newFile = getSelectedFile();
        System.out.println(newFile.getName());
        if (newFile.getName().matches(".*[\\\\/?<>:|\"%*].*")) { // Regex which matches if invalid characters present
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "The following characters are not allowed: \\ / ? < > : | \" % *");
        } else if (newFile.exists()) {
            int overwriteReturn = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "A file with this name already exists, would you like to overwrite it?", "File exists", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if (overwriteReturn == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) { // If the user chose to overwrite the file
                approveFileName = true;
            }
        } else {
            approveFileName = true;
        }
        if (approveFileName) {
            try {
                if (newFile.createNewFile()) {
                    super.approveSelection(); // Allow the dialog to close and the showSaveDialog() method to return APPROVE_OPTION
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "There was a problem saving the image; you might not have permission to save to the directory you chose.");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The only instance where I want to use this class is in this method in some other class:

```
public void someMethod() {
    FileSaver fileSaver = new FileSaver();
    int saveFileReturn = fileSaver.showSaveDialog(window);
    if (saveFileReturn == FileSaver.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File newFile = fileSaver.getSelectedFile();
        saveFile(newFile);
    }
}
```

This is fine for most filenames entered, but if the filename contains a question mark ("?") or asterisk ("*") then `approveSelection()` is not called and a new file filter is created (and appears set while the program mainly treats the file filter as its previous setting) with the filename as the description. Would it be possible to treat these filenames like any others (such that `approveSelection()` is called and the selected file set accordingly)?

e.g. this image shows the result of trying to save "nameWithQuestionMark?" in the desktop directory:

[image: Save Dialog]

Also, it seems as though a filename containing a forward slash ("/") is treated as a path relative to the current directory and thus `getSelectedFile().getName()` only returns the part of the filename after the slash (or removing a slash at the end of the filename) and the part before appended to the directory path. Would it be possible for `approveSelection()` to retrieve the full filename for validation and not alter the directory?

e.g. Entering the filename "dir/name" in the /home directory should give a selected file with path "/home" and name "dir/name" and keep the contents of the filename field as "dir/name". Instead, the selected file's path is "/home/dir" and the name is "name" and the filename field contains "name".